# By using the definition of $e$, prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{3+2x}{5+2x}\right)^x = \frac1e$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> By using the definition of $e$, prove that: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{3+2x}{5+2x}\right)^x = \frac1e.$$

I can solve it by using l'hospital rule. But how to use definition of $e$ to show it?

Comment: What is the definition of $e$?

Comment: You can write you limit
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{ ( 3x^{-1}+2 )^x }{ (5x^{-1}+2)^x }$$
Remember that from the definition
$$e^a:=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left( 1+\dfrac{a}{x} \right)^x$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\left(\dfrac{3+2x}{5+2x}\right)^x=\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac3{2x}\right)^x}{\left(1+\dfrac5{2x}\right)^x}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $e$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
e^x = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n
\end{eqnarray}
Try to get it to the format. I will edit it for the full solution if there are more problems arising.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{3+2x}{5+2x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{3+2x}{5+2x}-1\right)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{5+2x}\right)^x=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{5+2x}\right)^{-\frac{5+2x}{2}\cdot\frac{-2x}{5+2x}}=\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{5+2x}\right)^{-\frac{5+2x}{2}}\right)^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-2x}{5+2x}}=\frac{1}{e}.$$